# Suppose that the function f:(a,b) --> R is uniformly continuous. Prove that f:(a,b)-->R is bounded.

Tags: calculus

Also a second unrelated question,
suppose that the function $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous with $f (0)>0$ and $f (1)=0$. Prove that there is a number $x_0 (0,1]$ such that $f (x_0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $0 \leq x <x_0$. That is, there is a smallest point in the interval $[0,1]$ at which the function $f$ attains the value $ 0$.

Comment: Don't mix a second, *different*, question within the body of a first one. Better, write another question, and always try to include what self work have you already done.

Comment: You should ask these questions in two different questions.  Otherwise people will be confused about which question they're answering.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Prove that for $\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;f\;$ continuous in $\;(a,b)\;$ is *uniformly continuous* there iff  the one-sided limits

$$\;\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)\;,\;\;\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)\;$$

exist **finitely**